# GET endpoint with comma separated UUIDs Django

Tags: django, get, rest

I am new to Django. I am trying to add endpoint which gives user details back, with provided user ids. The endpoint url should look like `/users/?id=user1_id,user2_id...`

I already have a url and viewset for `/users/`. However I want to add a new one. I am able to write a code in viewset with get_queryset() which give me expected result. But I am not sure how do I add a url pattern for `/users/?id=user1_id,user2_id...` request, which should call the new viewset. Can anynone help me with understand what can I use here?

Answer (score 1):

For the view you can use

`def my_view(request, user_ids)`

And in urls use

`path('users/<str:user_ids>')`

Then in views you can parse the ids as `user_ids = user_ids.split(',')` that will give you the list of uuid user ids.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried this. My existing route ```/users/``` keeps overriding the new url point. Any thoughts?

Comment: Add a new view with the added parameter `user_ids` and use the names namespace attribute. You can also do it in the same view provided you need to make some changes to class methods